# Are Fair Folk charms supposed to cost 12xp for Eclipse caste?

Tags: exalted

In the core book, it says this regarding Solar Eclipse learning charms from other exalt types or fair folk:

> These Charms cost double the normal experience of Favored Charms to learn (usually 16 points).

"Usually" is where I'm raising an eyebrow here. In the errata, it states that Fair Folk pay 6xp to learn charms. The way I had originally interpreted what was stated in the core book was that whatever the cost of favored charms, Solar Eclipse must pay twice that in order to learn a charm from any other exalt type or fair folk. However, I have never seen any case where the cost would be different, which leads me to think I misinterpreted that sentence.

1. Are we supposed to use twice the normal cost of a charm when an Eclipse purchases something from another exalt type or fair folk? Or,
2. Are we supposed to use twice what a favored charm would typically cost a solar? In this case, are there any examples of this value -not- being 16xp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Otherwise an eclipse caste would also pay more then 16 XP to learn other charms belonging to other castes.

I've never seen an eclipse paying 20 XP for a dragonblooded charm.

There are some charms which can giv an exalted discounts on certain charms. I'd say that discount could affect the cost of these out of exalt type charms.

Don't ask me for the precise name of the charm right now. It's one that permanently discounts all TMA charms with 2 XP. This combined with the desire to learn MA charms in a specifically diffrent elemental style. (IE: the spear & shield style MA that became obsolete in 2.5)